# CSS files load but do not apply to the DOM (k8s)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, dom, istio

#### Expected behavior

When loading a page on my website, stylesheets referenced in the page's HTML are loaded by the web browser.

Those stylesheets' styles are applied to the DOM, styling the web page.

#### Actual behavior

When loading a page on my website, stylesheets referenced in the page's HTML are loaded by the web browser.

Those stylesheets' styles are **not** applied to the DOM, despite the requests to the stylesheets returning 200s and the response body containing valid CSS.

#### Setup

My website is in a Kubernetes cluster run on EKS.

In the cluster there is a pod containing 2 containers:

- nginx to serve web requests
- php-fpm, to which nginx delegates PHP execution

They share a volume, which includes the application code and its public/ directory, so nginx can directly serve static assets while delegating requests to .php files to the php-fpm container.

An ALB in the cluster links to an ingress gateway, which sends traffic to a virtual service, which sends it to my pod. The ALB does HTTP->HTTPS redirection and terminates SSL.

#### Additional info

I have tried in both Firefox and Chrome, clearing site data, and disabling the browser cache.

This is not an issue when running the site on my local environment (in Docker containers).

Here are screenshots illustrating the problem.

The website loads a number of stylesheets including `/css/diff.css`, which includes a `body { font-family: Arial }` style:
[image: css is loading correctly]

---

However, inspecting the page's `body` shows that the styles from the stylesheet are not applied (no styles from any stylesheet are applied, but this one point illustrates the issue):

[image: no styles applied to the DOM]

---

Here are the request and response headers to the stylesheet:

[image: css request and response headers]

---

And finally, here is the HTML that loads the CSS:

[image: link rel stylesheet html]

Answer (score 0):

nginx was serving the CSS files with header `content-type: text/plain`.

I needed to add `include mime.types` in my nginx config to return `content-type: text/css` for css files (and the correct mime types for other files based on their file extensions).

**`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:**

```
   http {
+    include mime.types;
     ...
   }
```